# Jquery-ui widget creation makes Qunit tests with Check for Globals active fail

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, qunit

While running my QUnit testsuite I (for the first time) checked the "Check for Globals" flag a test turned red with the failure that I had introduced a global variable which is the following:

```
window.jQuery110007089870080817491
```

The name is the same as the $.expando property and it seems like it some sort of unique identifier.

I have tried debugging the tests but I can't find out when this property is added to the window object.

I wonder if anyone knows what this is, what it is used for, and and what can cause this to get added (and not removed) to the window object.

Thanks
/Viktor

*EDIT:*

I managed to create a minimal example when this happens and it seems like it is a problem with jquery-ui.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Unit Tests</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lib/qunit/qunit-1.11.0.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/qunit/qunit-1.11.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(function() {
            test("Test spinner", function() {
                $("#spinner").spinner();
                ok(true);
            })
        });
        </script>
        <body>
        <h1 id="qunit-header">QUnit Test Suite</h1>
        <h2 id="qunit-banner"></h2>
        <div id="qunit-testrunner-toolbar"></div>
        <h2 id="qunit-userAgent"></h2>
        <ol id="qunit-tests"></ol>
        <div id="qunit-fixture">
            <input id="spinner" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This (as well as other tests modifying jquery-ui widgets) will fail when the QUnit Check for Globals flag is turned on. I tried running jquery-ui's own test-suite with this flag activated and their tests fails as well.

If anyone has a workaround for this it would be great, else I guess I'll have to live with disabling Check for Globals when running unittests involving jquery-ui.

Comment: It's the callback function for JSONP requests, which needs to be a global with an unique name.

Comment: Right, so at what point does this callback function get added to the window? Right now of one of my unit-tests fails since it introduces this global variable.

I guess this has something to do with how I mock my services and I'll need to read up on JSONP before I understand fully whats going on.

Comment: Read [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) then. It will be added somewhere in the bowels of `$.ajax`.

Comment: Yep I'm on it. Thanks for the pointers and I'll update this question when I find out what's going on.

Comment: OK, it doesn't look like you're doing a jsonp request in your example code. Another possible explanation would be that something stored data on the `window` object like `$.data(window,…)` - afaik that already happens when you're adding event listeners on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the creation of a spinner() method I found the following lines.

```
11063   // turning off autocomplete prevents the browser from remembering the
11064   // value when navigating through history, so we re-enable autocomplete
11065   // if the page is unloaded before the widget is destroyed. #7790
11066   this._on( this.window, {
11067      beforeunload: function() {
11068         this.element.removeAttr( "autocomplete" );
11069      }
11070   });
```

This binds an event listener to the window object which introduces the global variable. If you want your QUnit tests to pass with the check for globals flag on you'll have to call

```
$.spinner("destroy");
```

Or the equivalent on other jquery-ui widgets that can have "autocomplete" to clean up all event listeners on the window object.